# Repository returns empty list in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to write a simple REST to pull records from a table that was shared with me. Since the table doesn't have a default ID column, I embedded a pk column to the entity object. Please find the code below for your review.

The issue I'm facing is that the repository.findByMediaType, where mediaType is one of the entity properties, returns empty list. I made sure the query param is not null and there are records in the table for the param passed. I tried findAll as well but didn't work. I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code. I am new to spring boot and would like to know the different ways I can debug this.

**Service implementation class**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.hyb.enterprisedashboard.api.entity.Tenders;
import com.hyb.enterprisedashboard.api.repository.DashboardRepository;



@Service
public class DashboardServiceImpl implements DashboardService{

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashboardServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    DashboardRepository dashboardRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Tenders> getTenderByMediaType(String mediaType) {

        List<Tenders> tenderList = dashboardRepository.findAll();
        //findByMediaType(mediaType);

        tenderList.stream().forEach(tender -> {
            logger.info("Order {} paid via {}",tender.getId().getOrderNumber(), tender.getMediaType());
        });

        return tenderList;
    }

}
```

**Entity class**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "TENDERS")
public class Tenders {

    /** The id. */
    @EmbeddedId
    private TendersPK id;

    /** The dateTime. */
    @Column(name="DATE_TIME")
    private Date dateTime;

    /** The tenderMedia. */
    @Column(name="TENDERED_MEDIA")
    private String tenderMedia;

    /** The mediaType. */
    @Column(name="MEDIA_TYPE")
    private String mediaType;

    /** The tenderAmount. */
    @Column(name="TENDERED_AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal tenderAmount;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public TendersPK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(TendersPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the dateTime
     */
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param dateTime the dateTime to set
     */
    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tenderMedia
     */
    public String getTenderMedia() {
        return tenderMedia;
    }

    /**
     * @param tenderMedia the tenderMedia to set
     */
    public void setTenderMedia(String tenderMedia) {
        this.tenderMedia = tenderMedia;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mediaType
     */
    public String getMediaType() {
        return mediaType;
    }

    /**
     * @param mediaType the mediaType to set
     */
    public void setMediaType(String mediaType) {
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tenderAmount
     */
    public BigDecimal getTenderAmount() {
        return tenderAmount;
    }

    /**
     * @param tenderAmount the tenderAmount to set
     */
    public void setTenderAmount(BigDecimal tenderAmount) {
        this.tenderAmount = tenderAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tenders [id=" + id + ", dateTime=" + dateTime + ", tenderMedia=" + tenderMedia + ", mediaType="
                + mediaType + ", tenderAmount=" + tenderAmount + "]";
    }

}
```

**PK Embedded class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;


@Embeddable
public class TendersPK implements Serializable{

    /**  The Constant serialVersionUID.*/
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public TendersPK() {
    }

    /**
     * @param storeNumber
     * @param orderNumber
     */
    public TendersPK(long storeNumber, long orderNumber) {
        super();
        this.storeNumber = storeNumber;
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "STORE_NUMBER")
    private long storeNumber;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_NUMBER")
    private long orderNumber;

    /**
     * @return the storeNumber
     */
    public long getStoreNumber() {
        return storeNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param storeNumber the storeNumber to set
     */
    public void setStoreNumber(long storeNumber) {
        this.storeNumber = storeNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the orderNumber
     */
    public long getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param orderNumber the orderNumber to set
     */
    public void setOrderNumber(long orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (orderNumber ^ (orderNumber >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (storeNumber ^ (storeNumber >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof TendersPK))
            return false;
        TendersPK other = (TendersPK) obj;
        if (orderNumber != other.orderNumber)
            return false;
        if (storeNumber != other.storeNumber)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TendersPK [storeNumber=" + storeNumber + ", orderNumber=" + orderNumber + "]";
    }

}
```

**Repository class**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.hyb.enterprisedashboard.api.entity.Tenders;
import com.hyb.enterprisedashboard.api.entity.TendersPK;

@Repository
public interface DashboardRepository extends JpaRepository<Tenders, TendersPK>{

    @Query("select t from Tenders t where t.mediaType = ?1")
    List<Tenders> findByMediaType(String mediaType);
}
```

And I see the below query passed in the console

```
Hibernate: select tenders0_.order_number as order_number1_0_, tenders0_.store_number as store_number2_0_, tenders0_.date_time as date_time3_0_, tenders0_.media_type as media_type4_0_, tenders0_.tendered_amount as tendered_amount5_0_, tenders0_.tendered_media as tendered_media6_0_ from tenders tenders0_
```

Could anyone please help to find the cause?

Comment: What happens if you run the query manually?

Comment: @DonHosek it does return results if I just run the exact query in sql developer

Comment: I tried implementing CrudRepository just for the sake of testing but returned the same empty list. There is no error thrown nor exceptions caught. Am I missing something? Anyone, please?

Comment: In your `@Query("select t from Tenders t where t.mediaType = ?1")` try to replace `Tenders` with `TENDERS` because in your entity you have used all uppercase letters. Otherwise, try to use native Query like this `@Query(
  value = "SELECT t FROM TENDERS t where tMEDIA_TYPE = ?1", 
  nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: @FedericoGatti - Atleast findAll() should work right when I don't use @Query? But that did not. I used the query that you shared above but that didn't help either.

Comment: Could you try to use `@Query( value = "SELECT * FROM tenders where media_type = ?1", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: @PeterLustig - Again, that returns empty list. Now I feel that its got something to do with the oracle driver. I am using ojdbc7-12.1.0.2 jar. I had to download seperately and add to build path to get the application running. However upon startup - I see a warning in the console logs - `2020-03-04 11:07:04.858  WARN 13776 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.` What do you make of that?

Comment: Resolved. The DB connection was pointing to a different schema in the same database. Thank you all for the comments

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and it turns out my spring.datasource.* properties were not being set. I had them in the wrong file and the were not being read.

I would think that my repository query would error out if I had not provided datasource url, username, and password - instead I would simply just get an empty list returned.

I ended up figuring out that I was not pulling my datasource credentials by adding this in my RestController:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
String username;
```

Then I just printed username to the system.out.println. When starting the application I would get an error that spring.datasource.username was undefined. Hence I knew I was not loading datasource information that I thought I was.